# IBM toolchain app keeps changing when refreshing webpage

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ibm-cloud

I'm new to IBM cloud and I have been testing Toolchain to develop and deploy my code. I've been using Orion to edit my code online and git to commit, push it and deploy it. As you can see in the image everything seems to be running smoothly and with no problems.

[![Toolchain general visual
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWxKP.png

The problem is that when I enter the webpage where the code is deployed, it is showing a previous version of the webpage. I committed, pushed and synchronised changes but they only appear some times when I refresh the page. The webpage keeps changing randomly every time I hit the refresh button, sometimes showing the actual version and other times a previous one. Is this normal? Does anybody know why this keeps happening?

Thank you.

Comment: You would need to tell more about what type of code, how it is deployed, if you have multiple app versions live, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was happening is, somehow, Bluemix had created another instance of my toolchain with the suffix "OLD-xxxxxxxxx" and both the instance I was working on and the copy were deployed in the same URL, so they were colliding with each other.